# Is there any tool to optimize MySQL Queries?

Tags: mysql

I am  undergoing the performance test on MySQL and i need your guidance.If there is any tool available to optimize the MySQL Queries.Please let me know.The tool i am  seeking for is one which would be useful to identify the query which causing the memory leak.

Thanks,

Comment: why would a mysql query create a memory leak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using EXPLAIN in front of your query is a good starting point to understand what is going bad or too slow. So you can improve performances using primary/foreign keys and indexes.
A query, as Mitch Wheat said, doesn't produce a memory leak; maybe it takes a lot of time and consumes a lot of ram, but there are different reasons for this.

Comment: Hi @Marco thanks for reply.Can u explain reasons for memory consumption..?

Comment: @user626206: When you run a query, database engine reads table, join records, and many other things for which it needs to store data in memory. So, depending on how many tables are inside your query, joins requested and total records inside each table, engine could need a lot of work and memory. Using in correct way keys and indices could make your query run a lot faster than you imagine... but it depends on database. So my answer is really really general. Ah, sorry for my English.

Comment: Hi @Marco your assistance is really appreciatable.Once again thanks for reply.

Comment: @user626206: glad to help you. SO is here right for this :)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this - [EverSQL](https://www.eversql.com/sql-query-optimizer/). This seems to be a good tool, however it can only optimize select queries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one - [Query Profiler](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/query-profiler.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`

Answer (score -1):

User wampserver, it provides a mysql gui.