# SQL DateTime optimization - SLOW

Tags: mysql, datetime, optimization, mariadb

I'm trying to optimize a query which is taking way too long but can't seem to figure it out.

```
CREATE TABLE `syncs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `auto_retryable_after` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `times_auto_retried` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `UsedDate` (`status`,`auto_retryable_after`)
)
```

With this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM syncs WHERE status IN ('2','4') and auto_retryable_after <= NOW()
```

With 500,000 test records this takes roughly 16.5 seconds. I usually have a much larger data set which means it takes multiple minutes. So any help would be appreciated!

Comment: see: [Is there any tool to optimize MySQL Queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633593/is-there-any-tool-to-optimize-mysql-queries)

Comment: *With 500,000 test records this takes roughly 16.5 seconds.* How many rows does this query selects?

Comment: @Akina it selects them all.. I though the INDEX would resolve it, but to no avail.

Comment: Noway to optimize, I think. Get this query profile - I think that 99% of estimated time is data transfer.

Comment: Wy do you select records that a retryable after a datetime too long ago?  Maybe add something like: `and auto_retryable_after > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -10 DAY)`   (where 10 is currently randomly chosen)  to select only records that are retryable from the last 10 days....  (But I do not know the specifications for this query, so only guessing )

Answer (score 0):

Shoveling 500K rows to the client will (1) take network time, and (2) choke the client.  What will you do with that flood of data?

When looking at a performance of a query, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  That may show that it shunned the index and simply scanned the table.  This would actually be faster.  If, instead, it used the `UsedDate` index, that would be quite slow due to bouncing between the index's BTree and the data's BTree 500K times.

If this is a test case flaw (namely that the real data won't need to shovel all 500K), then create a "real" test case and try again.

If you really need all 500K, then re-think the overall flow of data.  For example, if you just need a "count" of the number of such rows, MySQL can much more efficiently do the count and deliver 1 row instead of 500K rows.